# Update view after AJAX call succeeds and returns data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I'm a beginner working on a recipe search app which returns a list of recipes based on the ingredients the user puts in the search bar. I'm learning to use Angular since it's convenient and makes my code more manageable.

So far I have succeeded in making jQuery Ajax GET requests to the API of my database and have a list of JSON objects returned.

Here's my Angular controller declaration:

```
    var recipesData = []; // variable that will hold the returned data
    angular
       .module("awesomeapp")
       .controller("listController", listController);

    function listController () {
         var vm = this;
         vm.data = recipesData;
    }
```

And I have stuff in vm.data displayed elsewhere in my view.

The problem is, when vm.data is set to recipesData, it doesn't contain anything yet because the page has just been loaded, the user hasn't put anything in and there isn't any data returned yet.

What should I do so that vm.data can be set after the Ajax call? Or can it be set outside of the listController function?

I'm looking for an elegant solution for this so that it makes everything easier to maintain. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to not use jQuery and use Angular's $http service to retrieve the data. The even more proper way to do this is to create your own service that internally uses Angular's $http service to get the data.

So first you would create the service. Something like this:

```
angular
       .module("awesomeapp")
       .service("recipeService", recipeService);

function recipeService($http) {
     return $http.get(**url**)
}
```

Then your controller would look like something this:

```
function listController (recipeService) {
     var vm = this;
     recipeService.then(response) {
        vm.data = response.data
    }
}
```

You'll probably have more things on your service eventually, but that should get you going in the right direction. I'd highly recommend referring to John Papa's Angularjs style guide https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md for guidance on how to structure your app. You want to try to avoid using jQuery with Angular in general, but in particular, you want to avoid using it for things Angular does natively.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the reason why I'm using jQuery's ajax is because I need to attach many parameters to the url and ajax keeps everything nicely formatted in a json format. What would be a good way to do the same with $http?

Comment: Also, I'm confused about how recipeService.then(response) works. Is it the same as the callback function on success? How does listController know what "response" is in this case?

Comment: $http is Angular's equivalent to JQuery's ajax. You can pass parameters, it will also return JSON, etc.

Comment: $http returns a promise and when it resolves (finished the asynchronous call in this case) the then method is executed. You'll get a standard http response object back, with the data you requested in the data member.